# Search all method missing where argument in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a method in my controller to allow searching the results of my query on my view page. The query selects all results from the "ads" table and this method should allow filtering results by the ad's name inputting keywords in the search bar. 
The controller code goes like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $title = trans('ad.title');
        $ads = Ad::paginate(10);

        if (!empty($request->input('search_all'))) {
            $search_all = urldecode($request->input('search_all'));
            $ads->where(function ($query) use ($search_all) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search_all.'%')->get();

            });

        }else {
            // Returning to view
            return view('admin.ad.list')
            ->with('ads', $ads)
            ->with('title', $title);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run a search I get the following error: "Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::where()".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move your `->get()` from the `$query` line to after the function's `})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately  it made no difference :/

Answer (score 0):

At the top, when doing `$ads = Ad::paginate(10);` you have already pulled the results from the database so no more filtering can be done at DB level.

I'd do something like this instead:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $title = trans('ad.title');
    $ads = Ad::select();

    if ($request->input('search_all')) {
        $search_all = urldecode($request->input('search_all'));
        $ads->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search_all.'%');
    }

    // Returning to view
    return view('admin.ad.list')
        ->with('ads', $ads->paginate(10))
        ->with('title', $title);
}
```

Comment: Instead of Ad::select I had to use Ad::all(); otherwise it doesn't select anything. Still getting the same error message. Plus, if I put paginate(10) where suggested I find a new error: "Method paginate does not exist."

Comment: If you're using `Ad::all()` you're again pulling the results from the DB, so no further search or pagination can be done. `Ad::select()` should work just fine, but if it doesn't try replacing that line with `$ads = new Ad;`

Comment: Replacing Ad::all / select() to  $ads = new Ad, only? It ends up in a new error :/